# Unique users permissions

Tags: user

Im new in SP, I have the need to create a list where only three users can edit, add and eliminate items.

I tried putting on the list Unique Users Permissions and it looks like this:
[image: Screenshot of my list]

However it is not working, anyone can add and edit items... what am i doing wrong?? What can i do to make it work??

Comment: Have a look at this MS article and that should help you and provide you with info: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-and-manage-permissions-for-a-SharePoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782

Answer (score 1):

whenever a new list/library is added, it inherit all current the permission from the site. After we stop inheritance, previous permission remain there

go to list setting and check the permission for All users.  There might be some group in which contribute permission is given to all users.

> And please always mention which SharePoint version you are working on,
>   it help to understand the scenario.